# supabase edge function using only js not ts

Tags: javascript, supabase, deno, edge-function

I am trying to write a supabase edge function with deno.

But I can see that when I run this command.

### create edge function

```
npx supabase functions new FUNCTION-NAME
```

It creates a function file called index.ts but I am not comfortable with typescript.

Is there a way to create a function with on javascript?

Comment: If you can't find a solution here, it's worth noting that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. Thus you're okay to write pure JavaScript code inside index.ts.

Comment: Did you try changing the file's extension to `.js`? If that doesn't work, you can create a new JavaScript module (e.g. `main.js`) and write your code there. Then change the contents of the existing entrypoint module (`index.ts`) to `import "./main.js";` to load and execute it.

Comment: yes I did and it doesn't work. That is why i am asking the question here.